# Web Components and dependencies isolation

Tags: javascript, dependencies, web-component

Do web components really isolate dependencies inside each component?
I've imported two components in the same page and I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: JSON.stringify is not a function
```

Each of the components works fine when is alone in the page. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: please share more code

Comment: The library that conflicts is MooWheel (mootools-1.2-core-nc.js, mootools-1.2-more.js, excanvas.js, canvastext.js, moowheel.js)

with some of jquery.js, jquery-xdomainrequest.js and atmosphere-min.js.

Each group of libraries is imported in each one of my web components.

Comment: which browser do you use? Does it indicate from which file comes the uncaught error?

Answer (score 1):

It does not isolate dependencies, and it does not run in a sandboxed JavaScript. However, you can use Web Component **imports** to make sure your dependencies are downloaded and run only once:

1) Add the import to **each** of your Web Components html:

```
<link rel="import" href="dependencies.html" />
```

2) Then `dependencies.html` should contain any scripts you need to be run only once:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.2-core-nc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.2-more.js"></script>
....
```

The browser will download `dependencies.html` only **once on a page**, and run it only once. It will simply ignore the other imports of this same file after the first time.

More info here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

---

**Update, if you have different dependencies for each webcomponent:**

1) Add all the needed imports to **each** of your Web Components html:

```
<link rel="import" href="import-mootools-1.2-core-nc.html" />
<link rel="import" href="import-mootools-1.2-more.html" />
```

2) Then the import files should contain each one a single script you need to be run only once:

File `import-mootools-1.2-core-nc.html` contains only this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.2-core-nc.js"></script>
```

File `import-mootools-1.2-more.html` contains only this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.2-more.js"></script>
```

Note: If after that you still have problems, then it's not because you are including the dependencies more than once. See the Network tab at your console, and you will see it's downloaded only once. You probably have other issues there.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I have a different dependencies.html file for each of my components, I package each component individually and then I import them in an HTML file, but apparently the dependencies of one component affect the behavior of another.

Comment: Just create a different HTML file for each dependency, and include each of them with a separate import. For example, create a `mootools-1.2-core-nc.html` file that contains only `<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.2-core-nc.js"></script>` and then include it with `<link rel="import" href="mootools-1.2-core-nc.html" />`. Do this for all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I did it but didn't change anything. In any case, I already had the conflicting dependencies in different HTML files, and imported each one of them individually into different components and then package each one of them (so in theory the dependencies should have been resolved at this stage when they don't conflict), but when these 2 web components are imported into the same page, the conflicts still remain.

Comment: See the above update. If you are already doing this, then your problem is not a conflict of importing libraries twice (because then you are not), but something else. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

No, Web Components won't isolate external dependencies in general, if they deal with global objects or global context.

Your problem is that you are importing (at least) one library twice, and that library won't allow it.

Nothing related to Web Components anyway.

**Update**: also the polyfill webcomponents.js should not be imported twice.